# Cannot invoke initializer for type 'SCNMatrix4'

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm working on `ARKit` and trying to initialize `SCNMatrix` but its throwing following error:

Code snippet:

```
if let frame = self.sceneView.session.currentFrame {
    let mat = SCNMatrix4(frame.camera.transform) 

    return (dir, pos)
}
```

Error:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type ‘SCNMatrix4’ with an argument list
>   of type ‘(matrix_float4x4)’ Overloads for ‘SCNMatrix4’ exist with
>   these partially matching parameter lists: (float4x4), (double4x4)

Does anyone face something similar kind of issue?

Comment: Which Xcode/Swift version are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 9.0 beta1

Comment: It compiles without problems in my Xcode 9  beta 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using an old Xcode beta. Swift bridging for SIMD matrix types changed in Xcode 9.0 beta 2. (As of this writing, beta 3 is current.)

With said changes, `matrix_float_4x4` and `float4x4` are the same type, so your code should work fine.